# select query not returning expected result

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which is having 30 columns. And I have executed the below query (using postgres 9.1, executed via pgAdmin)

```
select column2 || '|' || column3 || '|' || column4 
from tablename 
order by column1 asc
```

I am getting 5 rows with empty result. and I noticed that column3 having values as 'Data1|Data2' while I execute select * from table name.

Any idea?

Table structure is simple. All are character varying except column1 (numeric) and data having simple texts except column3. Column3 having data with delimer ("|). i.e., 12345|23333

How can I achieve the same in this?

```
psql -d mydb-U user1 -c "\copy tablename to 
    '/home/user/table_data.csv' delimiter '|' csv header";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any of the columns is `null` the result of the concatenation using `||` is also null.

You can use `concat()` or even `concat_ws()` ("concat **W**ith **S**eparator") to make Postgres treat null values like empty strings:

```
select concat_ws('||', column2, column3, column4)
from tablename 
order by column1 asc;
```

Note that `concat_ws()` will not append the separator if a value is "missing". If you do need it, you have to use `concat()`

```
select concat(column2, '||', column3, '||', column4)
from tablename 
order by column1 asc;
```

Details in the manual:

[9.4. String Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

Regarding the last part of your question, you can use a `select` statement for the `\copy` command. For details please see the manual.

Comment: @horse, tried the following command. But didn't work psql -d mydb -U user -c "select concat(column2,  '|', column3,  '|' , column4) from mytable order by column1 asc limit 1 to '/path/test/range1.csv' delimiter '|' csv header";
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to"
LINE 1: ...mytable order by column1 asc limit 1 to '/path...

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the second part of your question, and your [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116769/select-query-not-returning-expected-result/116778#comment212410_116771) on *a_horse_with_no_name*'s [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116771/1192), try:

```
psql -d mydb -U user -c 
    "select concat(column2, '|', column3, '|' , column4) 
    from mytable order by column1 asc limit 1" 
    -to '/path/test/range1.csv' -delimiter '|' -csv header
```

(line breaks added for readability)

If that doesn't work just do:

```
psql -d mydb -U user -c 
    "select concat(column2, '|', column3, '|' , column4) 
    from mytable order by column1 asc limit 1"
```

Does the output look like you intend?  If so, do it again, but use an i/o redirect:

```
psql -d mydb -U user -c 
    "select concat(column2, '|', column3, '|' , column4) 
    from mytable order by column1 asc limit 1" > /path/test/range1.csv
```

...assuming /path/test/ exists as a path.

Also, did you intend to do something like this?

```
psql -d mydb -U user -c 
    "select column2, column3, column4 
    from mytable order by column1 asc limit 1" 
    -to '/path/test/range1.csv' -delimiter '|' -csv header
```